# VSCode debugger does not work when cross-env is set

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, inspector

This is my test script. For some reason, when `cross-env` is called, vscode debugger doesn't work

```json
{
    "test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-specifier-resolution=node' NODE_NO_WARNINGS=1 mocha test/**/*.{spec,test}.[jt]s --require test/prelude.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you set `NODE_OPTIONS` using the `cross-env`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=\"${NODE_OPTIONS} --experimental-specifier-resolution=node\" NODE_NO_WARNINGS=1 mocha test/**/*.{spec,test}.[jt]s --require test/prelude.js"
}
```

To append to ${NODE_OPTIONS}, it will work!

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I just created this question to answer it myself. I appreciate everything though :)